# How can I change the tracking branch color in git branch -avv?

Tags: git

When I use the command

```
git branch -avv
```

to see my branches and their tracking branches, my Windows command prompt displays the tracking branches in a very dark blue that's hard to see against the black background of the command prompt window.

I found a few pages on changing colors for `git branch`, but nothing that seemed to refer to this specific case.

Is there a way I can change that specific tracking-branch color?

Comment: Sure: configure your terminal emulator to use a different color for that.

Comment: @jthill, if you want to post an answer that shows how to do that in a Windows command prompt, feel free.  I'll accept the answer if it works.  I don't guess I have any use for that dark blue color, really.

Comment: <Alt>-Space, explore that for color settings.  Not on Windows atm but iirc it's pretty easy to find from there.

Comment: All that offers me is Screen Text, Screen Background, Popup Text, and Popup Background.  There's no way to change that specific dark blue color to a different specific color.